# Multiply input by order and sum multiplied result then print

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hey guys I'm new to python and right now I'm stuck in this:
Get user number input like "`98751`", then multiply them by order and sum the multiplied result like this:

```
"9^1" + "8^2" + "7^3" + "5^4" + "1^5"
```

So far I got here without input:

```
num = 34532
x = [int(a) for a in str(num)]
print(x)
a=1
multilist = [number * a for number in x]
print(multilist)
```

then print the result.
Thanks in advance

Edit:
final result for whoever needs it, thanks to **Jhanzaib Humayun**

```
num = input("Please enter desired number: ")
sumn = 0
for i in range(len(num)):
    sumn+=int(num[i])**(i+1)

s = [int(n)*(i+1) for i,n in enumerate(num)]
print("Multiply result by order:")
print(s)
print("Final result:")
print(sumn)
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take the [tour], read [what's on-topic here](/help/on-topic), [ask], and the [question checklist](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648), and provide a [mre]. "Implement this feature for me" is off-topic for this site. You have to _make an honest attempt_, and then ask a _specific question_ about your algorithm or technique.

Comment: what have you tried ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
num = input("Input a number: ")
sum = 0
for i in range(len(num)):
    sum+=int(num[i])**(i+1)
print(sum)
```

Edit: You can use something like this if you want to use list comprehension

```
num = "34532"
s = sum([int(n)**(i+1) for i,n in enumerate(num)])
print(s)
```

By using `enumerate`, you get the index `i` and the element `n`. Which you can use according to your needs, and lastly `sum` can be used to sum upp all the elements in the array.

Comment: This got the job done, btw is it possible to print the sum and multiplied result separately?

Comment: If you want the multiplied result, then call the array something else and save it in a variable: `mult_arr = [int(n)*(i+1) for i,n in enumerate(num)]`. After that you can have another variable that is the sum: `s = sum(mult_arr )`.

Comment: The first version of the code raises values to a varying power whereas the second version does multiplication thereby producing different results. Also, the first version obliterates the built-in *sum* function. But it's the accepted answer so...

Comment: @LancelotduLac oops, mb. Meant to use `**`.

Answer (score 0):

If the number is presented as a string then:

```
num = '34532'

sum_ = sum(int(n)**i for i, n in enumerate(num, 1))

print(sum_)
```

**Output:**

```
257
```

**Alternative:**

```
sum_ = sum(n**i for i, n in enumerate(map(int, num), 1))
```